# How is an eigenvalue equation inverted?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$A$ is an invertible matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ and eigenvectors $\bar{v}_i$. Then

$$A\bar{v}_i = \lambda_i\bar{v}$$

I realise that the eigenvalues of $A^{-1}$ would be $\lambda_i^{-1}$, but what about the eigenvectors?

$$A^{-1}\bar{w}_i = \lambda_i^{-1} \bar{w}_i$$

What can be said about $\bar{w}_i$?

In my case, $A$ is a real symmetric 3x3 matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since $A$ is inverible, and

$A \bar v_i = \lambda_i \bar v_i, \tag{1}$,

we know that all the $\lambda_i \ne 0$, so we can just multiply (1) through by $\lambda_i^{-1}A^{-1}$, and *voila!*, we obtain

$\lambda_i^{-1} \bar v_i = A^{-1} \bar v_i, \tag{2}$

which shows an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to $\lambda_i$ is an eigenvector of $A^{-1}$ associated with $\lambda_i^{-1}$.  And if we multiply (2) by $\lambda_i A$, we see that the correspondence works both ways.  This works for any nonsingular $A$, the size of $A$ doesn't affect the result, and it appears that the symmetry of $A$ is not used here either.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 1):

Hint: multiply both sides of your first equation by $A^{-1}$.

Comment: Ooh. I should have thought of that. Thanks!